# Radius of convergence of series with $a_n = \frac{\sin(n!)}{n!}$

Tags: power-series

What is the radius of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(n!)}{n!} x^n$ ?

Since in $\{a_n\}$ we have $a_n=\frac{\sin (n!)}{n!}$. So $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded sequence. Hence radius of convergence $R>1$. But how to proceed further ?

Comment: From the assumption $a_n$ is bounded, we can only conclude $R \geq 1$, not $R >1$.  In any case try to show $\sum |a_nx^n| \leq f(|x|)$ for some function $f$ you can identify.

Comment: Maybe have a look into what the radius of convergence of the power series for $e^z$ is?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes $R\geq 1$, my mistake. But how does the latter helps ?